# Delphi - Drag and Drop .txt Files in TMemo

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, tmemo

I'm Trying to drag and drop text files into my Delphi app memo1 and load the text. Just like
what notepad.exe does ! when dragging any file it loads the text inside of it. but i am trying to only load specified file extension ! to accept loading on memo1.text.

Example: when dragging `text.txt` file to `memo1` it loads the text inside of `test.txt` 
but when dragging `.exe` into `memo1` nothing happens or just display error message.

I searched Google and tried my self but i have no answers to my question ;c .

any help will be much appreciated since i got no idea about drag and dropping text into memo.

Comment: hows my question is dupe ;c ? I don't think it duplicated 
i hope someone answer me guys.

Comment: Use the code in the accepted answer there and implement `DropAllowed` by checking the file extension. Essentially this question merely asks how to implement a drop target.

Comment: it's just hard ;c could you give me an example. i want just simply drag and drop any file to load in memo1. just usin ondragover and ondragdrop events if possible.

I am trying to learn this but i have no idea how

Comment: It sounds as though you aren't experienced enough to code this yourself. In which case a component is useful. Look at the other answers at the dupe. One links to this component: http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop

Comment: I tried this component and it seems not working with xe. I also tried using it with D7 and still the same. BTW I'm using windows8.1
and yep ;c I'm still beginner and can't code it myself hmm ;c.

Comment: I guess you need to keep trying

Comment: That component is supplied with source. You can compile it yourself. This guy documented how to do it for XE2: https://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/Drag+and+drop+for+Delphi+XE2